# Is the meaning of "you only live once" backwards?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

People say "you only live once" when they're trying to justify taking a risk or talk someone into taking a risk. But shouldn't the idea that you only live once discourage you from taking a risk?

> "Should I throw this toaster in the bathtub?"
>   "You only live once!"

To me, an appropriate response would be:

> "You're right; maybe I shouldn't do it."

But it seems like the expected response is:

> "You're right; might as well try it!"

Comment: The idea is that you only have one lifetime, so you might as well make the most of it and do crazy things—no point in being careful and ‘saving’ the crazy, fun things for another lifetime, because there won't be one.

Comment: it's a question in philosophy, not English.

Comment: This demonstrates what can go amiss when attempting to extract literal sense from a figure of speech. **YOLO** is a halting expression of the epicurean cry - *carpe diem* or *gather ye rosebuds while ye may.* It might make slightly more sense if rearranged as *you live only once,* but the acronym **YLOO** lacks zip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about inappropriate *reasoning*, not "use of English" as such.

Comment: [I couldn't resist!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5Otla5157c)

Answer (score 1):

The phrase of "you only live once" highlights the relatively short time that we have to do anything on this planet. People say it when they're taking risks that they're not entirely sure of, because they may not have an opportunity to try it. When faced with a new situation, you can either take the risk or shy away from it. If you don't take the risk now, you might as well resign yourself to never doing the activity in question, since you only live once and won't get another chance.